# NO MODULE NAMED TKCALENDAR

Tags: python-3.x, import, sudo, xlwt, tkcalendar

I have installed the tkcalendar and xlwt using `pip3 install tkcalendar` and `pip3 install xlwt` which is successful and have up to date versions.

Running the code using the command as `python3 /home/pi/programename.py` works perfectly 
Using `sudo` before the command like `sudo python3 /home/pi/programename.py` fails with error

> ImportError: No module named tkcalendar.

Instlling `tkcalendar` module using `sudo apt-get install tkcalendar` gives error like `E:Unable to locate package tkcalendar.` Please help me how to install the package and clear the error.

Comment: It was resolved by using "sudo pip3 install tkcalendar"

Comment: If you are using ubuntu, then tkcalendar is not in the main repository, but as explained in the install section of the [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) in a separate PPA. Moreover, the package name is `python3-tkcalendar`.

Answer (score 3):

Try again with

> pip install tkcalendar

If you use python 3:

> pip3 install tkcalendar

And check with:

> from tkcalendar import Calendar

Comment: Thank you. I tried all those instructions but didn't work for me.

Comment: Finally I resolved this error by using "sudo pip3 install tkcalendar".